# NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key string not popup a alert view

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I have add the `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` key to the `info.plist` file just like the `NSLocationUsageDescription` key, but when I initialise `CBCentralManager` in code, it is not popping up an alert view to display the message in the `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` key.

For example, when we add the `NSLocationUsageDescription` key in `info.plist`, when app try to use your location information, it will popup an alert view, but it is not work as `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` key. **why?**

Comment: Do you have any updates on the same ? i am facing the same issue.

Comment: only when iPhone play Peripheral role It will display the popup view. like you can add the code [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil]  when you init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a key-value in info.plist in xcode project

Privacy-Bluetooth Always Usage Description:

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app need your bluetooth</string>
```

and when u init a CBCentralManager, the parameter options should contain CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey

```
    let dict = [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:true]

    //if init the manager in sub thread queue, when u got some event, u need to update UI in the main queue
    //entralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: centralInitQueue, options: dict)

    // the queue paramter is nil, manager will dispatches central role events using the main queued
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` is only needed if you have one of `bluetooth-central` or `bluetooth-peripheral` in `UIBackgroundModes` in `Info.plist`:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
   <string>bluetooth-central</string>
</array>
```